# Why is apc_fetch not returning upload progress?

Tags: php, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, apc

I'm attempting to get the progress of a file upload but apc_fetch does not return an array for this:

```
$status = apc_fetch('upload_'.$_REQUEST['progress_key']);
```

The file upload completes successfully with no errors. I have apc.rfc1867 enabled. I know that APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS must be the first param being sent to the server. I'm uploading with XMLHttpRequest, and the APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS is being sent to the server in the query string.

The upload is occurring on a virtual host on my server. I have APC enabled in /etc/php.d/apc.ini

Here is the Javascript I'm using for the upload:

```
xhr.open('POST', queryURL, true); // queryURL var contains APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name', encodeURIComponent(filename));
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');               
xhr.send(input.files[0]);
```

It also does not work in IE9 when I'm using an iframe for the upload.

Why does apc_fetch not return the upload progress array?

Comment: i think you want progress bar when file uploading time. Am i right?

Comment: That's correct. But in order for the progress bar to work I need to retrieve the upload progress data with apc_fetch, which I am unable to do.

Comment: I have send code in my answer i am using jQuery progress bar With file upload in php. please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Is your `APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS` hidden field located BEFORE the file input tag in your form?

Comment: Thanks for your tip Jeroen, I had it working fine on 1 page and couldn't work out why it wasn't working on the 2nd page.

Comment: @Jeroen Moons. Can APC be used to get individual file progress?

Comment: @Samir If you have one file input in an upload form, you provide a key, which you generate yourself (hidden field with name 'progress_key'), After that you ask APC for the progress on that key (so you get the progress on that one file). If you have multiple file inputs in one form I'm not sure if tracking is possible using this approach. You should be able to bind a key to each file input to do that but I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: @Jeroen Moons. Thanks. I just wanted to know if someone has tried that and seen if it works. All the examples point to a single form-level upload progress status. I guess I will have try and check myself.

Comment: @Samir No problem. If you know more after investigating this, please post some feedback here.

Answer (score 0):

Demo url:--

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/progress.html

You can download jQuery file from this url and add in html tag

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js

http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js

Try this:-

// this is my html markup

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Progress Demo #1</title>
<style>
body { padding: 30px }
form { display: block; margin: 20px auto; background: #eee; border-radius: 10px; padding: 15px }

.progress { position:relative; width:400px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px; }
.bar { background-color: #B4F5B4; width:0%; height:20px; border-radius: 3px; }
.percent { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>File Upload Progress Demo #1</h1>
    <code>&lt;input type="file" name="myfile"></code>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="uploadedfile"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
    </form>

    <div class="progress">
        <div class="bar"></div >
        <div class="percent">0%</div >
    </div>

    <div id="status"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
     bar.width("100%");
    percent.html("100%");
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 

})();       
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My php code:

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm looking forward to reviewing this, but the issue I'm seeking to resolve is on the server side -- the apc_fetch function isn't returning the value I'm expecting. I'm having no trouble with the actual file upload.